# Access to setters in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm asking myself which is the best way to get access to setters in a web-application.

Basic example:

- a Band has properties
- Only the Band members has the access to change those

And here starts the question, what is the best way to provide this.

The way I usally use, is to write a service class, which is called in every method.
for example:

```
public function changePropertyAction ($bandname) 
{  
    if(!BandAuthService::isBandMember($bandname)) {
        // redirect
    }
    // change the property to a new one
}

public function changeAnotherPropertyAction($foo)
{
    if(!FooAuthService::isFooMember($foo)) {
        // redirect again
    }
}
```

Is there another way, in this way in every action the user calls, the system has to check if it is an bandmember ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good practice to manage rights on objects is to use ACL (Access control Lists). ACL could be seen as the Symfony roles system but applied on each object in your database.

So, each record in DB has an Owner, who have all accesses on it ; but you also can give some rights to other users, like View, Edit,...

Finally you check right with something like :

```
$securityContext->isGranted('EDIT', $band)
```

You can find a simple presentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html) and more details on ACL [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl_advanced.html).